# How to pluralize a symbol

Tags: objective-c, xcode, doxygen

I am using doxygen for my Xcode project. It automatically generates links for symbols automatically and it is awesome. However, I need to use plural to keep the sentence grammatically correct. e.g., Persons. But if I add the 's' in the end, it breaks the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add % markdown in between to keep the link. For example Person%s

Comment: Works not just for Objective-C, but for whatever code.

Comment: As far as I see, this useful feature is not yet described in Doxygen's manual.